# Need netsh reference for various Windows versions

Tags: netsh

After searching over and over again I can't seem to find a netsh command reference per windows version. I'm using Python to run some netsh commands but the customers may have different Windows versions: Vista ,XP, win7, win10, win8, Windows server etc..

Did anyone encounter a full reference per Windows version?

I'm looking for this since I bumped into one difference today between XP and win7:

XP -> netsh interface ip show config
win7 -> netsh interfate ipv4 show config ( this one would fail in XP - the image below shows why)

[image: Win7 Vs WinXP - netsh one difference ( one of many ? )]

Thanks for your help,
Sivan